# Need RegEx Pattern to get text between delimiters at start of text

Tags: regex, applescript

My source text could be any number of characters between "[" an "]" at the beginning of the line.  I will have ONLY one line.
For example:

```
 [1] and some other text here
 [10] more text, but maybe some brackets [KEY]
 [1000000] a lot more text
```

I want to match/return the text between the "[" and "]".

---

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER PROVIDED**

**The first answer, provided by @nickb worked for me** with this AppleScript:
Note that I had to convert the RegEx to a quoted string to use in AS.  This uses the [Satimage AppleScript Additions](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/dictionaries/dict_satimage.html) `find text` command, which provides the RegEx engine for AppleScript.

```
set strRegEx to "^\\[(.*?)\\]" -- Original: "^\[(.*?)\]"

set strTextToSearch to "[10] My Note title with [KEY] "
set strCaptureGroup to find text strRegEx in strTextToSearch using {"\\1"} with regexp and string result
log strCaptureGroup

-->10
```

Comment: Is that the only thing that will be on a line? Can there be something after the characters in brackets?

Comment: I think you need more examples to illustrate the breadth of matches you're trying to capture. It's not very clear whether or not you need to match `[` or `]` characters inside the outermost delimiters.

Comment: @Turn: as my examples show, there can be anything after the right bracket "]"

Comment: @Jessee Sieiaff : As I posted in my original question:  I want to match/return the text between the "[" and "]", so the brackets must be found, and the characters inside the brackets must be returned as a Capture Group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple regex you could use would be this:

```
^\[(.*?)\]
```

You can see it matching your input [here](http://regexr.com/3cef4).

Comment: This worked!  Thank you very much.  See my AppleScript code above in my edited question.

Comment: @JMichaelTX: If this is the answer you consider most useful, please remember to come back to accept it.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, and it is not obvious how to "accept" and answer.  For anyone else wondering about this, you click on the big checkmark just below the arrow to "dislike" the answer, in the left panel.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively a pure AppleScript solution

```
set theText to "[1] and some other text here
[10] more text, but maybe some brackets [KEY]
[1000000] a lot more text"

set resultList to {}
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "]"}
repeat with aLine in (get paragraphs of theText)
    if aLine starts with "[" then set end of resultList to text 2 thru -1 of text item 1 of aLine
end repeat
set text item delimiters to TID

resultList -- {"1", "10", "1000000"}
```

Comment: While it's nice to have an alternate solution, this one does not use RegEx as I requested in my question.  RegEx seems the best solution to be because it should be faster, and requires less code.  Not sure why this answer is getting more likes than any of the RegEx answers.

Comment: Regex is not always faster. The goal is to write the most effective code, not the shortest code. Text item delimiters is pretty fast. Applying regex to AppleScript needs some overhead because it's not built-in.

Comment: In this case, I'm using the Satimage.osax which is a scripting addition, just like Apple's own ScriptingAdditions.osax.  String & character processing through Satimage is almost always faster than the very limited string functions provided by Apple.  This use case is a very simple use of RegEx.  BTW, the goal is not to write the most effective code.  It is, IMO, to get an acceptable job done with the least effort.

Comment: @vadian when one line of code is up against eight lines of code, I think it's time to say "don't do it that way".

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fit your criteria:

```
^\[([^]]*)\].*
```

With the stuff in brackets in the first matching group returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try runing the following reg. exp. on each line:

```
[^\[]\w+[^\]]
```

I tested it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it matches the contents inside the `[]`, excluding the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\[(.*?)\]/
```

is [really](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347551/4554883) the most simple regex for this case, but it matches surrounding brackets too.
The exact value (without brackets) is stored in [1st capture group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html).

If you don't want to match brackets, you will need this:

```
/(?<=^\[).*?(?=\])/
```

---

… unless you're using JavaScript – unfortunately, JS doesn't support [lookbehinds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

In this case you'll need this regex:

```
/^[^\[\]]+/
```

*(assuming that every input will start with `[…]` component, and will not be empty)*

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Parzhitsky, for you clear and detailed answer.  The 1st capture group provided the results I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to use depends on how you are going to use it for the input it will parse.  Some of the answers here have a trailing .* and some do not.  Both are correct, it just depends on what exactly you are trying to match, and crucially how you ask it about a match.  For example, in Java, with the regex `^\[(.*?)\]`, if you feed it the whole string "[1000000] a lot more text" and call `matches()`, it will return false because the regex pattern does not account for any of the trailing text outside the brackets.  However, if you call `find()` after feeding in the same string, it will match because `find()` works on each substring as it parses and will return true on the first match it hits, while `matches()` will only return true if the entire input matches the regex. `find()` will also find subsequent substring matches to the regex in the string each time `find()` is called until the parser reaches the end of the input.

Personally, I like to use regex that account for the entire input and use capture groups to isolate the actual text I want to grab from the input. But your mileage may vary.